# Getting vagrant synced folders to work on windows with openstack

Tags: windows, vagrant, openstack, winrm

I'm using `vagrant-openstack-plugin` to handle openstack integration and it uses a builtin rsync synced folder provider, I can't get it to use the plugin I specify (winrm) even by hacking the code a little.

For the record I can get `rsync` to work (with `winsshd` and `cwrsync` and a junction point from `C:\cygdrive\C` to `C:\`), but it's *really* gnarly.

I'm open to non-ssh/non-rsync synced folder options for windows (NFS? SMB only works if the host is Windows), but I need the openstack plugin to respect my choice of synced folder plugin first.